# "secretProviderClass.yaml": no matches for kind "SecretProviderClass" in version "secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1" ensure CRDs are installed first

Tags: azure, azure-aks

getting the following error when trying to deploy a SecretProviderClass in AKS.
*
error: resource mapping not found for name: "azure-tls" namespace: "ingress-basic" from "secretProviderClass.yaml": no matches for kind "SecretProviderClass" in version "secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first*

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-tls
  namespace: ingress-basic
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:                            # secretObjects defines the desired state of synced K8s secret objects
  - secretName: ingress-tls-csi
    type: kubernetes.io/tls
    data: 
    - objectName: $CERT_NAME
      key: tls.key
    - objectName: $CERT_NAME
      key: tls.crt
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
    keyvaultName: $AKV_NAME                 # the name of the AKV instance
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: $CERT_NAME
          objectType: secret
    tenantId: **removedintentionally**
```

Tried to install above SecretProviderClass manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

**Install below dependencies:**
helm repo add secrets-store-csi-driver https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver/charts
helm install csi-secrets-store secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver --namespace kube-system